# Filling in a numpy ndarray with a 1d array and a mask/index of true/false values

Tags: pandas, numpy

Let's say I have the following:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
mask = np.array([[False, False, True], [False, True, False]])
values = np.array([20, 30])
```

I want to fill in the values of 20 and 30 in where the mask is true row wise so the result is:
[[1, 2, 20], [4, 30, 6]].

Also, how would I fill in the vector column wise so the result would be:
[[1, 2, 30], [4, 20, 6]].

How would I do this with just numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`X[mask] = values`. This works when `X.shape == mask.shape and len(values) == mask.sum()`.

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  2, 20],
       [ 4, 30,  6]])
```

For the second part of your question, you can transpose X and mask for the computation:

```py
X.T[mask.T] = values
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  2, 30],
       [ 4, 20,  6]])
```

See the [numpy  documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)